# Getting a list of APIs in a binary that are called by an android application

Tags: android, callstack

I have an android application that uses APIs from a binary file (.so). While I am running the app, I would like to get a list of all the APIs in the .so that is called by the application.

My initial thought is to create a service that would get the stack trace on every function call that happens and then to process that list. The glitch is, how can I get the stack trace on every function call in the application.

PS: I don't want to make logging changes to the existing APIs in the binary file, else I could have created the list of APIs from the logs.

Comment: "While I am running the app, I would like to get a list of all the APIs in the .so that is called by the application" -- just read the source code of the application and see which `native` methods it calls.

Comment: The binary has a large number of APIs. I cannot get the list just by reading through the code. I am looking for some automated solution.

Comment: Learn to use `grep` on the source tree?  Granted, that is static analysis, which is not always accurate in determining what is actually invoked at runtime.  Or you could try to implement something like an ltrace tool or generating a self-wrapped version of the library.

Comment: Since I need to get the list of methods actually invoked, static analysis wouldn't serve the purpose here. How could I make use of Itrace and would it work on android to get me the list of APIs invoked?